# Subtract and Add Inventory (SUMIF)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Inventory System that will be used by Users to both check-in and check out items. The SKU of each item will be matched through the File 
to either add or subtract from the Starting Quantity that is in Sheet 1.

Sheet 1 houses an SKU of each item in Inventory (column B), the Original Quantity (Column I) and Current Quantity (Column F) for each item.

Sheet 2 is the Checkout Sheet (SKU is Column C and Quantity Taken is Column F)

Sheet 3 is the Check-in Sheet (SKU is Column C and Quantity Added is Column F)

In Sheet 1, I need the Current Quantity Column to update as Items are either Checked In or Out from Sheets 2 and 3.

My formula for Sheet 1, Current Quantity Column:

```
=IF(B448="","",I448-SUMIF(CheckOUT!$C$2:$C$50000,B448,CheckOUT!$F$2:$F$50000)),(I448+SUMIF(CheckIN!$C$2:$C$50000,B448,CheckIN!$F$2:$F$50000))
```

Which receives an error of "#Value".

The beginning part of the formula,

```
=IF(B448="","",I448-SUMIF(AWCheckOUT!$C$2:$C$50000,B448,AWCheckOUT!$F$2:$F$50000))
```

successfully works by itself to deduct items as they are checked out from Sheet2.

Similarly, the ladder part of the formula,

```
(I448+SUMIF(CheckIN!$C$2:$C$50000,B448,CheckIN!$F$2:$F$50000))
```

successfully works by itself to add items as they are checked in from Sheet3.

However, when I combine the two formulas, a #Value error is returned.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this, please.

Thank you so much!

Comment: replace the `,(I448+` with `+(`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Scott! Adding the "+" does the following: Original Quantity is 5 in Sheet 1, Quantity Checked Out (subtraction) is 1 in Sheet 2, and Quantity Checked In (addition) is 1 in Sheet 3, meaning the Current Quantity should now match the Original Quantity of 5. However, after using the "+" in the formula the Current Quantity is now at 10.

Comment: Then you did not remove the second `I448` like I said in the comment.  You needed to replace the whole `,(I448+` with `+(` not just the `,`

Comment: Sorry, Scott. You are correct. The formula works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help! :)